# Multivariable constrained optimisation

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

How to determine if a solution exists for a multivariable (3 variables ) optimisation problem with 2 constraints? What conditions should i check?

Comment: Do you mean how to determine if a *feasible* solution exists, or an *optimal* solution? And, are you looking for an algorithmic approach or an analytical approach (i.e., a theorem)?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).